# Given an Array of strings, return an array of strings that contains only the palindromes

Tags: java, arrays, string

Helping a friend out with a question he had. For the life of me I can figure out why my code doesn't work correctly, I am sure it is something very simple I just need another pair of eyes to take a look at it,

```
public String[] bahB(String[] arr) {
    int count=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        String[] f = new String[arr[j].length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr[j].length(); i++) {
            f[i] = arr[j].substring(i, i + 1);
        }
        if(isPalindrome(f)){
            count++;
        }
    }
    String[] d = new String[count];
    int y=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        String[] f = new String[arr[j].length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr[j].length(); i++) {
            f[i] = arr[j].substring(i, i + 1);
        }
        if(isPalindrome(f)){
          d[y]=arr[j];
          y++;
        }
    }
    return d;
}

public boolean isPalindrome(String[] x) {
    int s1 = 0;
    int s2 = x.length - 1;
    while (s2 > s1) {
        if (x[s1] != x[s2]) {
            return false;
        }
        ++s1;
        --s2;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My code starts off by creating a counter that is supposes to get the amount of palindromes in the given String array, it is not an issue in the is Palindrome method so it must be something in the these lines

```
  int count=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        String[] f = new String[arr[j].length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr[j].length(); i++) {
            f[i] = arr[j].substring(i, i + 1);
        }
        if(isPalindrome(f)){
            count++;
        }
```

Thanks to anyone that took the time to read this

Comment: What data have you tested it with, and in what way is the result incorrect?

Comment: The issue is that the count variable is not iterating

Comment: Why does `isPalindrome` have a `String[]` as a parameter, instead of a `String`?  I would have expected it to test a single `String`, not a whole array of them.

Comment: @David Well the way I wrote this program it creates a string array out of the string. As a reach around to compensate for the oddly written isPalindrome method. In hindsight it would be better to just rewrite the isPalindrome method so it uses a String instead of a String[]. But the code is already fixxed and working.

Comment: Considering that your title is plain flat wrong: you do not have an array of Strings, you have an array of arrays of truly stupid one character substings, you ar wasting our time and earn my downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you decided that "it is not an issue in the is Palindrome method", since in point of fact, your `isPalindrome` is quite broken. This:

```
        if (x[s1] != x[s2]) {
```

means "if `x[s1]` and `x[s2]` are references to the same instance of `String`"; whereas what you meant is "if `x[s1]` and `x[s2]` are references to `String` instances with the same content", i.e.:

```
        if (!x[s1].equals(x[s2])) {
```

(though really, you shouldn't be using a `String[]` here anyway; you should use be using a `char[]`, or a `String` with `charAt`).

Comment: By the way, you should read about [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Your bug is not a huge deal, but your total inability to debug -- your dependence on "another pair of eyes" -- is a serious impediment. You will not be a programmer until you have overcome it.

Comment: huh well I repeatedly tested the isPalindrome method in eclipse and never had any issue with it that why I said "it is not an issue in the is Palindrome method", but I will I double check. Thanks for the responses

Comment: char array is faster than charAt method!!

Comment: @Prashant: I like that you're confident enough to include two exclamation points!!, but not confident enough to include actual benchmarking numbers to demonstrate that this makes a difference. (Hint: it doesn't.)

Comment: Your testing of `isPalindrome` probably used `String` literals as input.  Because of a quirk of the way Java handles Strings, `==` actually returns true if you use it to compare two equal `String` literals.

Comment: @ruakh : i have used both for large number of data (in loop). And there was huge different between these two in execution time.

Comment: @Prashant: Firstly -- what is your evidence that the OP has "large number of data (in loop)"? Secondly -- you do realize that this method iterates over each string only *once*? There is overhead in creating each string's `char[]` to begin with.

Comment: @ruakh : i don't think so that he is having large number of data. but as per me char array is faster than charAt and also string is internally having char array.